# How to include useRouter in function from one place with Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, firebase-analytics, next-router

I have a function in Next.js project that collects events for Firebase analytics.

```
import analytics from '@utility/firebase';

const handleLogEvents = (event) => {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  logEvent(analytics, event.event_name, {
    branch_slug: event.branch_slug,
    timestamp: currentDate,
    ...event.properties,
  });
};
```

For example, when a category is clicked, I ensure that the event is sent to Firebase.

```
const handleCategoryClick = (id, title, branchSlug) => {
  const event = {
    event_name: 'category_click',
    properties: {
      branch_slug: branchSlug,
      category_id: id,
      category_name: title,
    },
  };
  handleLogEvents(event);
};

const { query } = useRouter(); 
const { branch } = query; // I have to call events on every page I post.

return(
  <div onClick={() => handleCategoryClick(id, title, branch)}>Example Div</div>
)
```

I call events in multiple functions (product, category etc.). The routes I use in my project are dynamic. Every time I send an event to Firebase, I need to get the route name. Every time I call `handleLogEvents` I have to write the following code on the page:

```
const { query } = useRouter();
const { branch } = query;
```

**Do I have a chance to use `handleLogEvents` in a function instead of calling this `useRouter` every time I call it?**
Every time I use this function, it seems unnecessary to go and call the router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move `handleLogEvents` to a re-usable custom hook where you enclose the `useRouter` value.

```js
import { useCallback } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import analytics from '@utility/firebase';

export const useLogEvents = () => {
    const { query } = useRouter();
    const { branch } = query;

    const handleLogEvents = useCallback((event) => {
        const currentDate = new Date();
        logEvent(analytics, event.event_name, {
            branch_slug: branch,
            timestamp: currentDate,
            ...event.properties
        });
    }, [branch]);

    return { handleLogEvents }
};
```

Then, you simply have to call the custom hook to retrieve the `handleLogEvents` function with the right `branch` value from the router.

```js
const SomeComponent = () => {
    const { handleLogEvents } = useLogEvents();

    const handleCategoryClick = (id, title) => {
        const event = {
            event_name: 'category_click',
            properties: {
                category_id: id,
                category_name: title
            }
        };
        handleLogEvents(event);
    };

    return (
        <div onClick={() => handleCategoryClick(id, title)}>Example Div</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: const { query } = useRouter(); -> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Comment: You have to call `const { handleLogEvents } = useLogEvents();` inside a React component. See my updated answer.